# how can I give a p tag a class in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hell I want to give a p tag a specific class name, but I cant find how to do it. I want to give a the p tag a class, because I want to style it with css.

```
<?php
/* this plugin makes advanced custom fields*/

/**
 * Voeg de parent thema's stijl toe.
 */
ob_start();

function ultra_child_enqueue_parent_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ultra-parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ultra_child_enqueue_parent_style', 8 );

function ultra_child_enqueue_scripts() {
    //Plaats hier de javascript bestanden.
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ultra_child_enqueue_scripts', 8 );

/**
 * Plaats hier overige code in functions
 */
/* here I already make some p tags, but it generates an extra p tag and I 
   want to give that p tag an class to style it in the css 
*/
```

/* here I already make some p tags, but it generates an extra p tag and I 
       want to give that p tag an class to style it in the css 
    */
  /* here I already make some p tags, but it generates an extra p tag and I 
       want to give that p tag an class to style it in the css 
    */
  /* here I already make some p tags, but it generates an extra p tag and I 
       want to give that p tag an class to style it in the css 
    */
  /* here I already make some p tags, but it generates an extra p tag and I 
       want to give that p tag an class to style it in the css

```
// ACF custom field excerpt
function review_excerpt() {
    global $post;
    $text = get_field('review'); //Replace 'your_field_name'
    if ( '' != $text ) {
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]&gt;', ']]&gt;', $text);
        $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
        $excerpt_length = 60; // 20 words
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '<a href="'.$permalink.'" rel="nofollow"><br>Lees Meer</a>');
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    return apply_filters('the_excerpt', $text);
}

// foto vergelijking ophalen en als object weergeven.
function get_foto($image){    
     if( !empty($image) ) {
         echo $image['url'];
     }    
}

/* Registreer Recensies
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$labels = array(
    'name' => 'Recensies',
    'singular_name' => 'Recensie',
    'add_new' => 'Recensie toevoegen',
    'add_new_item' => 'Quote',
    'edit_item' => 'Wijzig recensie',
    'new_item' => 'Nieuwe recensie',
    'view_item' => 'Bekijk recensie',
    'search_items' => 'Zoek recensie',
    'not_found' =>  'Geen recensie gevonden',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'Geen recensie in de prullenbak gevonden',
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Recensies'
);

register_post_type('recensies',array(
    'public'=>true,
    'show_in_menu'=>true,   
    'show_ui'=>true,
    'labels'=>$labels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports'=>array('title'),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    /* developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons */
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-editor-quote',
    'taxonomies'=>array(),
    'exclude_from_search'=>false,
    'rewrite'=>true,
    'rewrite'=>array( 'slug' => 'recensies', 'with_front' => true ),
    'menu_position' => 4
    )
);


/* Registers picture before and after they have been posted. 
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$labels = array(
    'name' => 'Foto vergelijking',
    'singular_name' => 'Foto vergelijking',
    'add_new' => 'Foto Voor en Na toevoegen',
    'add_new_item' => 'Foto Voor en Na',
    'edit_item' => 'Wijzig foto vergelijking',
    'new_item' => 'Nieuwe foto vergelijking',
    'view_item' => 'Bekijk foto vergelijking',
    'search_items' => 'Zoek foto vergelijking',
    'not_found' =>  'Geen foto vergelijking gevonden',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'Geen foto vergelijking in de prullenbak gevonden',
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Foto Voor en Na'
);

register_post_type('fotovergelijking',array(
    'public'=>true,
    'show_in_menu'=>true,   
    'show_ui'=>true,
    'labels'=>$labels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports'=>array('title'),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    /* developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons */
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
    'taxonomies'=>array(),
    'exclude_from_search'=>false,
    'rewrite'=>true,
    'rewrite'=>array( 'slug' => 'voorenna', 'with_front' => true ),
    'menu_position' => 4
    )
);


?>
```

Comment: I don't know if i am overseeing this or not but i can't find any p tags?

Comment: yes sorry that i did not memtiond it, but I make post in the wordpress custom fields (in a wordpress text field) . so the text field generates its own p tag and in that p tag I want to give a class.

Comment: Would you mind giving us more code then?

Comment: sorry I'cant, because stackoverflow banned me for three days

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the class to the HTML in the theme?

Comment: thanks for the comments, a colleague of mine find the answer he used wp_trim_words